Spring Boot @LastModifiedBy annotation doesn't work on entity but works on String
I have some entity in Spring Boot app:
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;

}

Here is the auditorProvider Bean:
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorProvider")
public class JpaAuditingConfig {

    private final AuthService authService;

    public JpaAuditingConfig(AuthService authService) {
        this.authService= authService;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
        return () -> Optional.ofNullable(authService.getUsername());
    }

}

And AuthService class:
@Service
public class AuthService {

    private final UserService userService;

    public String getUsername() {
        return SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.userService.getByUsername(this.getUsername());
    }
}

Above solution works fine, when lastModifiedBy field is type of String.
But I would like to use User class instead of username. So I have modified the auditorProvider() as below:
@Bean
public AuditorAware<User> auditorProvider() {
    return () -> Optional.ofNullable(authService.getUser());
}

and Book entity:
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Book {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime lastModified;

    @ManyToOne
    @LastModifiedBy
    private User lastModifiedBy;

}

So basically I have replace String with User and now I get StackOverFlow error when trying to save the Book entity:
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at s\src\java.instrument\share\native\libinstrument\JPLISAgent.c line: 884
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction

Caused by: jakarta.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:561)
    ... 115 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError

Why is it happening?

Auditing information gets added in JPA lifecycle listeners. JPA is pretty restrictive about what you may or may not do in these listeners. One thing you must not do is change references to entities.
As in many cases the exact behaviour depends on the JPA implementation used.
I suspect in this case adding the reference triggers another event, which sets a reference, which triggers another event ... resulting in a StackOverflowError.
